# Why is AJAX running twice within WordPress function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Similar questions have been asked but can't find a solution. I have a click event that calls a php function (in wp), however, the function is being called twice. What am i missing?

```
$(document).on('click', '.cat-list_item', function(event){
   console.log("this gets printed once");
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
        action: 'filter_projects',
        category: $(this).data('slug'),
        type: $(this).data('type'),
      },
      success: function(res) {
        $('.webinar-tiles').html(res);
      }
   });
});
```

then the filter-projects function:

```
function filter_projects() {
  $postType = $_POST['type'];
  $catSlug = $_POST['category'];
  $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => $catSlug,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'desc',
  ]);
  $response = '';
  echo 'this gets printed twice?';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
```

Comment: Are the `.cat-list_item` elements nested within each other? How have you determined it's called twice per click? Where and when do you bind the event handlers - are they repeated?

Comment: the cat-list-item links arent nested. just have 3 of them after each other: <a class="cat-list_item" href="#!" data-slug="<?= $category->slug; ?>" data-type="post"><?= $category->name; ?></a>. if you see the on click event - the console log gets printed once. if you see the php function, it gets printed twice

Comment: What's happening in your browser's network tab?  Is there a single call?  Looks like a php problem rather than jquery/js

Comment: Add `return false;` as the last line of your jquery click handler and see if that fixes it

Comment: @freedomn-m return false; didnt fix it. I think you're right about being a php problem. there is a single call in the network tab. it feels like filter_projects is being called twice. but not from that js function.

Comment: @jkstallard have you fixed the issue? please share the code it would be very helpfull.

Comment: sorry, this never got resolved.